# Fancybox deleting image from gallery when I press it instead of popping it out and then putting it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, image

I have installed this [gem](https://github.com/kyparn/fancybox2-rails) . I got it working adding this coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
  $('img.fancybox').fancybox()
```

I have an array of images that also have a thumbnail, I want the thumbnails displayed and when you click on a image_thumbnail the full image should pop-out and let me navigate through the entire gallery of images. However when I click a thumbnail, it will display a thumbnail when it pops out, there are no navigation links and when I press the X link it won't put the thumbnail back where it was, deleting the image from the view(I get it back if I reload). This is how I display my Images:

```
<div class="fancybox-content">
  <% @product.attachments.each do |p| %>
    <%= image_tag p.picture.url(:thumb), class: "fancybox" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me achieve the desired output or give me hints of how I could achieve this?

Note: I can provide any other code that is needed